# jQuery Sessions, is there such a thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

Is there possibly a way to store jQuery sessions without any plugins?  If not, what plugins seem to work best in 'your' opinion. Is it possible to get a good solution for my problem without even using a session?  I'm still an amateur to jQuery, but know my way around it.

My task @ hand is a 'members bar' which gets toggled via a button, and always sticks to the top of the page.  Now if they login, it automatically closes the bar, and I want to get around it.  So a session seems like the way to go, considering I have it set to display: none; by default.

I have been looking through the web and done some research on it, but have come up with nothing useful for my case.

Here is my code, it is VERY simple and works without flaw at the moment.  This is done with WordPress and is on document ready.

```
    $('#member-focus').click(function() {
            $( "#bar-content" ).slideToggle("slow");
    });
            // Would like to check if toggle is supposed to be open
            // If it is, set #bar-content to display: visible;
```

Comment: Cookies or local storage?

Comment: I'm not overly worried about doing cookies, just as a session.  I don't want it to be 'open' if they leave for a day and come back, the members bar toggle button is obvious.  So a session will suffice, if they close the browser, when they come back it closed.  

I do believe sessions are stored on server, at least with PHP.

Comment: I am probably mistaken but are you looking to store the state of an element after a user interacts with it so that it is consistent between page loads and maybe even stays if the user clears cache/cookies? Kind of how Windows is able to remember the dimensions of the window you've just closed such as Word, Chrome, or a simple explorer window?

Comment: Yeah, if bar is toggled (and opened) then I want it to save a 'session' saying that it is indeed open.  So that way if they navigate to another page, it will remain open.  Then if they decide to close it, it will update the session saying that it's closed, or even 'terminate' the session.  Either way is fine.

Comment: @MrJustin The most consistent way to achieve this is to store a value in a database and update that value via AJAX whenever the element is toggled or whatever. Upon every page load you would pull in the latest data from the DB and program accordingly. I think WebSockets would be of interest to you depending on whether or not the overhead of AJAX is worth it to you. Web browsers do self-cleaning sometimes so a user might lose settings.

Comment: I don't want to modify the database as of yet, in the case I can find another option down the road.  This isn't overly vital, just wanted a little customization.  Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I'm aware that my suggestion is overkill but I just wanted to broaden the horizon in case you ever do implement a system which could use those features in an extensive amount of places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take advantage of the html5 `sessionStorage`, data will be stored as long the browser window or tab is open (or session is restored), an example of usage would be:

```
// saving an item
sessionStorage.setItem("bar", "top");
// querying content
sessionStorage.getItem("bar")
```

note that `sessionStorage` is binded to a  single window (or tab) , if you want to retain data across different windows, consider using `Cookies` or `localStorage`(same API as `sessionStorage`).

if you want to support old browsers (non HTML5), you can simulate the Storage API using Cookies(here's a [sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Compatibility))

Comment: I will look into 'localstorage' and return shortly.

Comment: 'localStorage' and 'sessionStorage' are similar, but not the same. localStorage sticks around much longer.

Comment: @Katana314, the difference is the scope, SessionStorage scope is the current window, it is cleared once window is closed, in the other hand, localStorage scope is the current domain, and is retained even after the browser is closed.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading into that.  I'm not really wanting to keep it at HTML5 due to browser supporting.  I think I'll wait a while, maybe come back and play around with it down the road, or upgrade it in 2.0.  It's not harming anything at the moment, and it does change the title from 'Member Panel' to 'Welcome %username%', with an arrow icon.  Well thanks for everything guys, I appreciate it.  Your information was useful and will be selected as correct answer.

Comment: I've added a sample to simulate `localStorage` for old browsers, if you want to take a look.